# Adsense only works within the body of index.html but not in any react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script, server-side-rendering, adsense

Regardless of multiple articles available online I have been suffering to understand adsense behavior with SPA applications like React js, we use the advantage of components here and when placing the adsense snippet the usual `<ins>` and

```
adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

Inside the index.html `<body>` tag it works but the same snippet does n't display any impressions on any of the react components(inside jsx). Adsense has many compatability issues with react and other SPA than traditional jquery/vanilla Javascript.

I have tried installing third party npm react libraries like [react-adsense](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adsense) etc.. But that doesn't work and it only works when the code is directly under body tag but not in any child jsx components.

Did anyone ever face this kind of problems with adsense. I have also posted in their community forum but it did n't help much.

Hope someone explain better. Thank you

Comment: How do you execute `adsbygoogle.push({})` call? Is it rendered in html by react or you call it from JS itself after react component has been rendered (don't know exact lingo of react lifecycle). Overall rendering AdSense from JS is quite straighforward: first add `<ins class="adsbygoogle">` element on the page and after that call `adsbygoogle.push({})` to trigger ad loading in that <ins> element.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau, I have tried placing it in JSX and also tried using hooks like useEffect()  to push once the component is rendered but still no difference in the behavior.

Comment: We are using [@ctrl/react-adsense](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ctrl/react-adsense) and no issues loading in inside jsx. Only problem we had that we had to put the main `<script ....adsbygoogle.js>` at the bottom of the index.html not in the head. Due to the blocking nature of JS it rendered better at the end. I am yet to try lazy loading and other options for third party scripts.